# Running batch file or explorer.exe doesn't have full functionality/privilege

Tags: inno-setup

I've built an Inno Setup installer and am having some issues with my final step.

Initially I wanted to run a batch file upon completion (from the `[Run]` section). This batch file starts a `yajsw` service, and uses `java.exe`.

I ran into a problem where the batch file wouldn't recognize `java.exe`, even if I added it to the path locally or pathed directly to it in `system32`.
I thought this could have something to do with Java not being in `sysWOW64`, and being on a 64-bit machine.

Anyway, some requirements changed and I ended up simply opening an instance of `explorer.exe` in the appropriate folder (that has several batch files) and giving directions as to which one to use. I do this in `CurStepChanged()` when `curStep` is `ssDone`, by using `Exec()` (or `ShellExec`).
It seems that even double-clicking these batch files from this explorer window has the same problem of not recognizing `java.exe`, but if I manually open an explorer window it works just fine.

I'm not sure if it matters but the test machine I'm using it on is running Windows Server 2008. I've tried using `PrivilegesRequired=admin`, and I've tried calling `ShellExec()` as well as `Exec()`, and I've tried `EnableFsRedirection(False)`.

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks!

EDIT: Since I'm not calling the batch file directly any more, and just trying to open the containing folder:

```
[Setup]  
AppId={{264F5847-C34C-4DB1-9EBF-F4D730D7E846}  
AppName={#MyAppName}  
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}  
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}  
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}  
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}  
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}  
DefaultDirName=C:\TestInstall  
DisableDirPage=yes  
DefaultGroupName=foo  
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes  
OutputDir=C:\Project\installer  
OutputBaseFilename=setup  
Compression=lzma  
SolidCompression=yes  
UninstallFilesDir={code:InstallPath}  
SetupIconFile=foo.ico  
UninstallIconFile=foo.ico  
SetupLogging=yes  

...snip...  
[Code]  
...snip...  
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);  
var  
  ResultCode: Integer;  
  cmd : String;  
begin  
  if CurStep = ssDone then  
  begin  
    cmd := 'explorer.exe';  
    ShellExec('', cmd, InstallPath('') + '\server', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode);  
  end;  
end;
```

and the batch file in the `Installpath\server\` directory just is (basically...there are a couple batch files that all use java):

```
java.exe {various params}
```

Basically, even if I just have `java.exe`, whether I fully path to it or add to the path locally, it doesn't work in the Explorer window that Inno fires off, but it DOES work if you open another one manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're running explorer with the wrong permissions.  Use `ShellExecAsOriginalUser` instead, or (better) use a `[Run]` entry with `Flags: postinstall shellexec` and a suitable `Description`.

(Also, if you want to try going back to running java, then you could try using the `useapppaths` flag, or querying the registry to find the correct path to Java.)

Comment: So `ShellExecAsOriginalUser` seems to have helped a bit, but still has the problem that it can't find `java.exe` on the 64-bit server machine because it's only in `system32` and not in `sysWow64`. Even if I path specifically to `system32\java.exe` it still can't find it, so I'm guessing it doesn't have access at all to `system32` from Inno Setup. This sounded a bit like an `EnableFsRedirection` issue, but that didn't seem to help either.